# Mobile reverse navigation (back) and Auto forwarding pages

Tags: mobile, navigation, back-button

I have a couple of questions:

1. When a user press back within a flow - do you show (when going back) screens that are "confirmation states" or steps that were needed to be field in order to continue the flow?
   Such as a confirmation code that was already sent and was confirmed?

If so:

- Do you clear the form?
- Keep the information field?
- Show a message that this step was already taken?

2. When going back - how do you treat states that are created in the server (such as pending / success confirmation)?
   Usually this states don't have a back button, or a continue option - and auto direct you to the next screen. But i don't want to confuse the user by removing it.

Is there a common practice when confirmation / validation screens can be auto transition and when it's better to keep the user in the page and let him manually continue the flow?

I'm attaching an example for a courier app:

- The courier has a list of goods
- When pressing continue he needs to input a verification code that was sent to the client
- Then the server is processing the payment (the client have field he's credit card details already)or alternative checking the code.
- And in the end - he signs the screen.

My question is - what should happen when the courier presses the back button on the last screen?
(we have a requirement to allow it)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**When a user press back within a flow - do you show (when going back) screens that are "confirmation states" or steps that were needed to be field in order to continue the flow? Such as a confirmation code that was already sent and was confirmed?**

I don't see the point. The pin entering screen should be the last screen where the user is allowed to back out. Why? Because otherwise it might create more confusion later. Will the payment be reversed? Will the delivery be signed or not? You will have a harder time explaining this because you don't know where and when the flow has been interrupted. Therefore,

After the pin screen is displayed you can cancel or move forward.

Then the payment can be made or the user can cancel it. No back button. If they cancel, bring them back to the main page not the pin page.

If confirmed, the transaction happens (no back button)

Then the transaction is signed (no back button).

After this , add a "cancel order" button on the order list item and everything will reverse.